# New to java and finding difficulty compiling with dependencies

Tags: compiler-errors, apache-tika

This is a complete rookie question - so my apologies.  I'm expanding my horizons and diving into Java.

I'm trying to compile some java classes that import from Tika dependencies.

```
import org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
```

I guess I thought if i put my java file in the same directory as the tika-app-1.6.jar directory, that the compiler would find what it needs.  Its returning 19 errors of symbols it cant find.

so, i've tried :
    javac test.java,
    javac -classpath "" test.java,
    javac -classpath "tika-app-1.6.jar" test.java,
    javac -classpath "*.jar" test.java,
    javac -classpath "*" test.java.

but really, I'm just missing something.  So the question is, what do i have to do to get this stuff to compile?

Comment: Apache Tika has lots of dependencies, so building by hand isn't recommended. Any chance you could switch to using Maven to build? Maven will handle downloading dependencies + putting them on the classpath for you

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok to create your project anywhere. Most IDEs have the ability to resolve the dependencies and allow it to run.

However perhaps you should read the [getting started guide](https://tika.apache.org/1.4/gettingstarted.html) for more

Comment: Why are you pointing the OP to an old version of the Tika docs? 1.7 is the latest